# Typo in help center: closed closed question

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

I found this typo in the help center page regarding closed questions, at the bottom of the following page:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

> between an `[on hold]` question and a `[closed]` closed one

I think we only need to say:

> between an `[on hold]` question and a `[closed]` one

This typo is part of the help center that is replicated to all sites, [including meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), so it should be an easy fix.

Comment: making sure the question is well and truly closed?

Answer (score 4):

What, you don't want two closures for the price of one?

This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: I fixed that for you. :)